# APNS accepts push messages, but they are never come to target

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying, to add apple push notifications for my backend server services, but i faced an issue, that i cant understand.
I'm using Pushy library [(com.relayriders.pushy)](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy).
My code is just like their github page recommends.
Code is works, there is no exceptions, push looks like formed properly. Push sends to APNS, but never comes to device.
Device token and certificate are correct to, my friend sent push to target device through his test program.
I also tested [com.notnoop.apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)  library with the same result - no exceptions and still no push on device
Here is my sender class:

```
package ua.asprelis.communicator.push;

import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsEnvironment;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.FailedConnectionListener;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.PushManager;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.PushManagerConfiguration;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.RejectedNotificationListener;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.RejectedNotificationReason;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.util.ApnsPayloadBuilder;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.util.MalformedTokenStringException;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.util.SSLContextUtil;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.util.SimpleApnsPushNotification;
import com.relayrides.pushy.apns.util.TokenUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException;


public class ApplePushNotifier
{
    private final PushManager<SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushManager;

    private final ApnsPayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = new ApnsPayloadBuilder();

    public ApplePushNotifier() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/certpath/cert.p12");
        this.pushManager = new PushManager<>(
            ApnsEnvironment.getSandboxEnvironment(),
            SSLContextUtil.createDefaultSSLContext(URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "UTF-8"), "password"),
            null, // Optional: custom event loop group
            null, // Optional: custom ExecutorService for calling listeners
            null, // Optional: custom BlockingQueue implementation
            new PushManagerConfiguration(),
            "ExamplePushManager");
        pushManager.start();
        pushManager.registerRejectedNotificationListener(new MyRejectedNotificationListener());
        pushManager.registerFailedConnectionListener(new MyFailedConnectionListener());
    }

    public void sendpush(String message, byte[] token) throws InterruptedException {
        String payload = payloadBuilder.setAlertBody(message).setSoundFileName("ring-ring.aiff").buildWithDefaultMaximumLength();
        pushManager.getQueue().put(new SimpleApnsPushNotification(token, payload));
    }

    public void sendpush(String message, String stoken) throws InterruptedException, MalformedTokenStringException {
        byte[]token = TokenUtil.tokenStringToByteArray(stoken);
        String payload = payloadBuilder.setAlertBody(message).setSoundFileName("ring-ring.aiff").buildWithDefaultMaximumLength();
        SimpleApnsPushNotification notification = new SimpleApnsPushNotification(token, payload);
        pushManager.getQueue().put(notification);
        System.out.println("Queued: "+notification);
    }

    public void closeSender() {
        if(pushManager!=null) {
            try {
                pushManager.shutdown();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ApplePushNotifier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyRejectedNotificationListener implements RejectedNotificationListener<SimpleApnsPushNotification> {
        @Override
        public void handleRejectedNotification(
            final PushManager<? extends SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushManager,
            final SimpleApnsPushNotification notification,
            final RejectedNotificationReason reason) {
            System.out.format("%s was rejected with rejection reason %s\n", notification, reason);
        }
    }

    private class MyFailedConnectionListener implements FailedConnectionListener<SimpleApnsPushNotification> {
        @Override
        public void handleFailedConnection(
            final PushManager<? extends SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushManager,
            final Throwable cause) {
            if (cause instanceof SSLHandshakeException)
                // This is probably a permanent failure, and we should shut down the PushManager.
            else
                System.out.println(cause);
        }
    }
}
```

And test class for running push:

```
@Test
public void testPushMessage() {
    Random random = new Random();
    String testMessage = "Hello Test! "+random.nextInt(1000);
    String testToken = "e6878d3993abfaec48220b9d4d3ea0b576c22351c7fbbb5faeb5449bf7f24452";
                      //e6878d39 93abfaec 48220b9d 4d3ea0b5 76c22351 c7fbbb5f aeb5449b f7f24452

    ApplePushNotifier notifier=null;
    try {
        notifier = new ApplePushNotifier();
        notifier.sendpush(testMessage, testToken);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(applePushNotifierTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (notifier!=null)
            notifier.closeSender();
    }
}
```

And my output:

```
[main] INFO com.relayrides.pushy.apns.PushManager - ExamplePushManager starting.
    Queued: SimpleApnsPushNotification [token=[-26, -121, -115, 57, -109, -85, -6, -20, 72, 34, 11, -99, 77, 62, -96, -75, 118, -62, 35, 81, -57, -5, -69, 95, -82, -75, 68, -101, -9, -14, 68, 82], payload={"aps":{"alert":"Hello Test! 955","sound":"ring-ring.aiff"}}, invalidationTime=null, priority=IMMEDIATE]
    [main] INFO com.relayrides.pushy.apns.PushManager - ExamplePushManager shutting down.
```

I feel that problem is in some tiny piece, that i cant see. It would be strange if both tested libraries dont work

Comment: Are you testing your app with a developpement provisionning profile or a production provisionning profile ?

Comment: yep, i used production certificate, but set my sender class to sandbox mode. Thanx

Comment: You are lucky, I made the exact same stupid mistake last week so it was still fresh in my mind :)

Comment: can any one tell me what is `SimpleApnsPushNotification`. I am getting a error in this as : SimpleApnsPushNotification cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I am using maven dependency `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relayrides</groupId>
    <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>`  but there is no class like : `com.relayrides.pushy.apns.PushManager`

Comment: what maven dependency version or jar did you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said - i had silly mistake. What a dumb i am. I used

> ApnsEnvironment.getSandboxEnvironment()

instead of

> ApnsEnvironment.getProductionEnvironment()

in both libraries.

That was first time im using APNS.

Comment: Hi i got this error 

The constructor PushManager<SimpleApnsPushNotification>(ApnsEnvironment, SSLContext, NioEventLoopGroup, ExecutorService, BlockingQueue<SimpleApnsPushNotification>, PushManagerConfiguration, String) refers to the missing type NioEventLoopGroup

Any idea about this error?

Comment: OK,I got it correct netty jar file not added in my class path

Comment: what maven dependency version or jar did you used?